# Alaric's impression in the first Grey Knights book

Tags: warhammer-40k

**SPOILERS AHEAD AND IN COMMENTS**

In the first Grey Knights book written by Ben Counter why is Alaric so contempt on believing that

> Tancred's body could not be found - Alaric knew that it never would be.

When Mandulis' body was found along with his sword after killing Ghargatuloth?

Comment: I have not read the book, but all Grey Knights are psykers. Is there any mention/reference/examples to his abilities? I would argue that he could "feel a disturbance in the force" and knew something more sinister was happening?

Comment: He isn't feeling it since squad Santoro lost some marines and Alaric didn't notice until they defeated Ghargatuloth. So the "disturbance in the force" is excluded. @Odin1806

Comment: Ahh, good luck with your answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer lies in the second book, *"Dark Adeptus"*, and it reads

> Justicar Tancred and his Terminator squad could have pooled their psychic power and called up the cleansing fire the Chapter's Chaplains called the Holocaust.They could have forced their way through with their massive terminator armour and Tancred's own sheer strength. But Tancred and his squad were dead, annihilated so completely Alaric hadn't even been able to recover their bodies from Volcanis Ultor. Alaric's squad was on its own here, surrounded and exposed.

So, apparently Tancred's body was utterly destroyed and nothing could be brought back to Titan for the Grey Knights' usual funeral.

But this [wh40k wiki](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Grey_Knights_Justicar) tells us otherwise.

> Although the Sword of Mandulis was recovered, neither Tancred's body nor his battle-plate were found at the scene of the terrible fight, which has left some to speculate that he might yet still live within the mind-altering eddies of the Warp.

So I'll take the word of god and consider him dead. Another good battle-brother dead, shame.